# Is Track Stick™ On DELL's Laptop Supposed To Come Off That Easy?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop-repair, trackball

I have this little button trademarked by DELL as **[Track Stick™](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick)** comes loose:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RIb7HV1bKA&hd=1

[image]

Is it supposed to be like this and I should leave it or better to glue it properly so it won't get lost? If to glue, which glue should I use?

Comment: @slhck Why you added picture to my question?

Comment: The question is, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As becomes obvious from this [supporting document](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd620/en/UG/keyboard.htm), it is perfectly fine that the Track Stick Cap can be removed:

[image]

The amount of force required to remove the cap will vary depending on the age of the cap and/or laptop.

If you feel the cap comes off too easily, replace it. If you don't feel like replacing it, try not to use superglue (in case you want to replace the cap later).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the rubber part of the trackpoint is supposed to come off, there's no need to glue it on.

<strike>On a related note, thanks to the cap being easily detachable like that, you should be able to use ThinkPad trackpoint caps, which some people report have a better feel than the ones Dell (and HP) use. ThinkPad caps are easily obtained from eBay, should you wish to try them out.</strike>
Disregard this note, it doesn't seem to apply to Dell Latitudes (at least recent ones).

Comment: If its only the rubber part thats coming off, then its as intended. But it seems like the hard plastic base is coming off as well(cannot make out from the video). In that case, its broken. Also, are Thinkpad and Dell caps interchangeable? My thinkpad cap doesnt look like it would fit on the OP's Keyboard

Comment: @Akash It seems pretty obvious in the video that only the rubber part is coming off. As for the caps, I think you may be right - I checked on a recent Dell Latitude, and looks like the actual pointing stick under the cap is smaller than on ThinkPads. My mistake, I'll strike that part of my answer. ThinkPad caps work fine on my HP EliteBook, though.

Comment: @Indrek How do you strikethrough? I can't find code in help section of SU.

Comment: @Boris_yo Like so: <strike>text here</strike>